# How to get all selected values from check boxes with the same name

Tags: jquery

I have 3 check boxes with the same name but different ids, and with the values `OK`, `TX` and `NY`. Also have wrapper `div` that contains couple of `input`. If user selects `OK` or `TX` then i want to show `div`, if user selects `NY` alone then i want to hide `div`

if(`OK` || `TX`) then show
if(`OK` && `NY`) then show
if(`TX` && `NY`) then show
if(`OK` && `TX` && `NY`) then show
if(`NY`) then hide

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bma8Lx1w/2/)

```
<div class="m-3 w-checkbox-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold">Select states?</label>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" id="states0" name="states" type="checkbox" value="OK">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="states0">Oklahoma</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" id="states1" name="states" type="checkbox" value="TX">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="states1">Texas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" id="states2" name="states" type="checkbox" value="NY">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="states2">New York</label>
    </div>
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid d-block" data-valmsg-for="states" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="w-conditional d-none">
    <div>
        <div class="m-3 form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-clean="lowerCase" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid d-block" data-valmsg-for="firstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="m-3 form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-clean="lowerCase" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid d-block" data-valmsg-for="lastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function () {    

$("div.w-conditional").each(function (i, v) {      

            var name = "states";
            var expectedval = ["OK","TX"];
            var $div = $(this);

            $("input[name='" + name + "']").change(function () {                        
                    var cb = $(this);
                if (jQuery.inArray(cb.val(), expectedval) !== -1) {
                    $div.removeClass("d-none");
                }
                else {
                    $div.addClass("d-none");
                    $div.find("input").val('');
                }
            });

    });

});
```

The issue here is getting multiple values from selected check boxes. the `cb` variable above will always return single value. `$("input[name='states']").val()` also returns single value.

i want to get all selected values and check if any of the selected value exists in expectedValue

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all checked check boxes and can push values in an array as below:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=states]:checked").each(function(){
    cbArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

And then you can use this array in your code.